# Rabbitmq message arrival and respond time stamp

Tags: rabbitmq, timestamp

Is there a way to get the timestamp when a message was placed on the queue, from a consumer. Not when it was published, but when it actually made it to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

First, a correction - consumers do not "place" messages on queues, *publishers* publish messages to exchanges, which then route messages to queues.

Yo can use the [RabbitMQ message timestamp](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp) community plugin to add a timestamp when a message is published to RabbitMQ.

Please note that RabbitMQ does not guarantee that messages are actually routed to any queues. It's up to you to bind queues correctly to exchanges to ensure that your messages end up where you expect them.